# What does this line of code means using Iterator 'Student st = (Student)itr.next();'

Tags: java

I'm practicing ArrayList program. I would like to ask the meaning of this line.

> `Student st = (Student)itr.next();`

```java
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Student s1 = new Student(1,"owelcute",28);
        Student s2 = new Student(2,"lucas",2);
        Student s3 = new Student(3,"jor",30);

        ArrayList <Student> studentList = new ArrayList<Student>();
        /*
        declaring class Student in ArrayList
         */

        studentList.add(s1);
        studentList.add(s2);
        studentList.add(s3);

        Iterator itr = studentList.iterator();

        while(itr.hasNext()){

            Student st = (Student)itr.next();
            System.out.println(st.rollno + " "+ st.name + " "+ st.age);
        }

    }
```

Comment: Always read the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#next--). If you are using a good IDE, you can just hover over "next()" to view it.

Answer (score 1):

```
Student st
```

creates a variable st that is type student.

```
=(Student)itr.next();
```

sets st to the value of the next element that itr(the iterator) is pointing to. (Student) is a cast that ensures

```
itr.next();
```

is of type Student.

Answer (score 0):

This is explained in the doc for `iterator.next`: it gets the next item in the iteration.

If the casting `(Student)` confuses you then that is partly because the code is incorrectly using the raw `Iterator` type.

The code should be, more correctly:

```
Iterator<Student> iterator = studentList.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()) {
    Student student = iterator.next();
    ...
}
```

Or, even better:

```
for (Student student: studentList) {
    ...
}
```